# Polaroid Effect with Images in Python

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, imagemagick-convert, pythonmagick

I'm trying to take an image and add the following effect from imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#polaroid. I've searched for Python code examples and have been unsuccessful. I don't need to use imagemagick(wand, pythonmagick, etc.) this was just the only example of this I could find. I don't want to use the command line example like listed. I would love to be able to include it in my photo booth python code.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subprocess/commandline-based approach? This one is the easiest, and most powerful (access to all options). Wand seems not supporting it (polaroid), Pythonmagick doesn't even compile on my system and i don't know how deep these libs are intertwined (supporting everything). A cli-based approach could be quite clean with the use of python's [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: I'm not familiar with python's tempfile module. Do you have an example that could run the polaroid command within python script cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), you will need to implement the C-API methods `MagickPolaroidImage` & `MagickSetImageBorderColor`

```py
import ctypes

from wand.api import library
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image

# Tell Python about C library
library.MagickPolaroidImage.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # MagickWand *
                                        ctypes.c_void_p,  # DrawingWand *
                                        ctypes.c_double)  # Double

library.MagickSetImageBorderColor.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # MagickWand *
                                              ctypes.c_void_p)  # PixelWand *


# Define FX method. See MagickPolaroidImage in wand/magick-image.c
def polaroid(wand, context, angle=0.0):
    if not isinstance(wand, Image):
        raise TypeError('wand must be instance of Image, not ' + repr(wand))
    if not isinstance(context, Drawing):
        raise TypeError('context must be instance of Drawing, not ' + repr(context))
    library.MagickPolaroidImage(wand.wand,
                                context.resource,
                                angle)

# Example usage
with Image(filename='rose:') as image:
    # Assigne border color
    with Color('white') as white:
        library.MagickSetImageBorderColor(image.wand, white.resource)
    with Drawing() as annotation:
        # ... Optional caption text here ...
        polaroid(image, annotation)
    image.save(filename='/tmp/out.png')
```

[image: Polaroid effect with Python & wand]

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate the shadow? With bigger images, the shadow doesn't look very appealing!